How to insert string to cursor position in TextField on Button click?
I'm trying to create something like math editor and I want to implement convenient LaTeX code typing.
For this purpose I've created row of buttons that extends keyboard. It should contain special symbols like '\', '$', etc and constructions like \frac{}{}, \sqrt{} and other.
I want to insert this text to cursor position in TextField I'm currently writing to (on these buttons' click).
I used to do it using following code inside Row():
val inputConnection = BaseInputConnection((LocalContext.current as Activity).window.decorView.rootView, true)
...
onClick = {
    inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_...)
    inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_...)
}
...

But it can be used to write a couple of symbols only, like letters and digits. For example, I didn't find dollar symbol keycode in KeyEvent object. And it will be strange to simulate entering string like "\frac{}{}" using KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN - KeyEvent.ACTION_UP. Methods of BaseInputConnection other than .sendKeyEvent are not working for me (or I use them improperly). Any help would be is appreciated.
